# ASP.NET (MVC) Get username from URL http://username@myapplication.com

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to retrieve username from this

http://**username**@myapplication.com

type of address in ASP.NET MVC (optionally in ASP.NET) from current request?

Comment: From the current request or from a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx):

```
var uri = new Uri(someString, UriKind.Absolute);
var user = uri.UserInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the guaranteed string you might try something like:

```
string myString = "http://username@myapplication.com";

if(myString.Contains("@"))
{
    return myString.Split('@')[0].Replace("http://","");
}
```